# Android how to differentiate clickable links from other text

Tags: android, linkify

I have a ListView(with HTML text) which contains hyperlinks in it. 
I am using the following code to open the hyperlinks in browser :

```
holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.answerText);
        holder.txtTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        holder.txtTitle.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

While this works fine, I notice that sometimes text like "R.abc" or "foo.bar" are also recognised as URLs and opened as hyperlinks on click. 
How do I differentiate between these and actual hyperlinks ?

Thanks !

Comment: The problem is, foo.bar could be a URL (think google.com). You need to be more specific about what you think a URL is supposed to look like.

Comment: Yes, that way I think any two words separated by a '.' could be a URL. Isn't there any way to see if it is a 'valid' URL ?

Comment: That IS a valid URL. You could test whether it contains a http:// or similar. You could use regular expressions. However, here be dragons.

Comment: I think you have to use regular expression for it to check whether your text contain any url and if yes then is valid or not according to that regular expression.

Comment: use webview in that case you dont have to write anything for redirect